# Calculating Breakpoints of `background-size` Property

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a centered viewport who has a large image as its background.  Due to other elements on the page, we elected to have some breakpoints depending on the sizes of of these other elements.  So far so good, my layout works fine.

The one gotcha is that since the image used isn't tall enough, once it reaches a certain size the background-color shows and there are bars that are introduced on either side.  This has to do with the ratio of the image vs. the ratio of the viewport.

Solution with Bars:

http://output.jsbin.com/vecele

Now, the fix here is to find at what point the bars are introduced.  Anything larger than that size, down to the cutoff means the `background-size` needs to be changed to `background-size: 100% auto;` vs when before when it was set to `background-size: auto 100%;`

Fixed Solution:

http://output.jsbin.com/fonozagova/

Now my question is how do I mathematically figure out that "magic number" cutoff?  In my example, I just played with the window size to find the actual number I should use here, which really isn't optimal.

Comment: `Now my question is how do I mathematically figure out that "magic number" cutoff?`, that's css's processing job while we use percents :D

Comment: @NiCkNewman The rest of the breakpoints don't use percentage points; most of these actually refer to `sass` static variables that are set in a mixin.  It seems (to me) the root of the problem has to do with the size ratios between the image and it's viewable area.  If you can give me a good solution to this, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not set the background size to `cover`?  It will scale the the background image proportionally to fill the container regardless of what the size is.

```
div.container {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: [Mother of god...](http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/288/5/b/mother_of_god_by_rober_raik-d4cw2di.png) that might just work.  I had no idea there was a property for that!

Comment: Just to clarify for readers further on, there are some implementation issues with using `background-size: cover;` for Opera-mini users.  [Reference](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pseudo-element with a vertical-padding in % that will use elements width as reference. the ratio will be kept no matter width updates:

```css
.hero {
  background-color: #0a6ba1;
}

#header {  
  background-image: url('https://suretybonds.com/img/bonds/giant-header/inspector-1800.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  position: relative; 
}
#header:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
   padding: 26% 0 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 699px) and (max-width: 1465px) {
  #header {

  } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 699px) {
  #header {
 

  } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 500px) {
  #header {

  } 
}

/* extra for demo */
#header  {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:4vw;
  }
#header:before {
  vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="header" class="hero">resize window's width</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/lafosakeke/1/edit?output

Comment: forgot to mention: run snippet in full page mode  and then resize your browser :)